# Imaging devices selection is missing from device manager on Lenovo SL300

Tags: windows-7, camera

I recently upgraded from Windows XP to Windows 7 Home on my Lenovo Thinkpad. When I did, my integrated camera on my SL300 stopped working.

It was suggested that I reinstall the drivers. While installing the driver (everything going as normal), the process just seemed to stop with no information or notice given. No flags, nothing. As if I never tried to install a driver.

I went into device manager to see if it had installed and realized the whole "imaging devices" section is gone along with the integrated camera. On the net, I am only finding suggestions to reinstall the driver.

How do I get back the imaging devices section along with the integrated camera?

Answer (score 1):

Usually two big reasons for this.  One are crappy driver. I assume you've tried uninstalling them. The next order of business is to use device manager's "Scan legacy hardware" option.

Answer (score 0):

No Imaging Devices menu within The Device Manager for built-in web camera.

Mine was a loose connection at the camera board on HP Pavilion dv7-6b56nr with HP TrueVision HD.

After reseating the cable, the camera works just fine.

Read more about how I fixed it here:

[Re: Webcam Not Working - HP Pavilion dv7-4295us Entertainment Notebook PC](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Display-and-Video-e-g/Webcam-Not-Working-HP-Pavilion-dv7-4295us-Entertainment-Notebook/m-p/2194645#M58780)